# Vite Build error: Eslint [commonjs--resolver] No ESLint configuration found in package

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

I have a fairly standard app that uses Vue3/Vite.

My `vite.config.js`:

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import eslintPlugin from "vite-plugin-eslint";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    eslintPlugin({
      exclude: ["./src/service/**", "./node_moduels/**"],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: "./public",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});
```

And my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:vue/vue3-essential"],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["vue"],
  ignorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
  rules: {
    "vue/no-reserved-component-names": 1,
    "no-tabs": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": 1,
    "vue/multi-word-component-names": 0,
  },
};
```

I get this error when I build:

```
[commonjs--resolver] No ESLint configuration found in /Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/primevue/avatar.
file: /Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/primevue/avatar/avatar.esm.js
error during build:
Error: No ESLint configuration found in /Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/primevue/avatar.
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (/Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3962:19)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (/Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:3753:21)
    at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (/Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:989:18)
    at ESLint.isPathIgnored (/Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:678:26)
    at Object.transform (/Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/vite-plugin-eslint/dist/index.js:1:2348)
    at file:///Users/rizakhan/volt/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22695:37
```

Anymore information I can provide to help debug this?

Comment: Is your eslint config actually named `eslintrc.js`? If so you need to rename it to `.eslintrc.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You included lint script in your package.json as I also faced the same  issue due to missing script in my package.
`"lint": "eslint ./src --ext .ts"` (./src replace with the folder for the files you want to apply lint.)

Second thing If you are building any important application then you don't want plugin coz the plugin is developed by an external user. So we shouldn't use that plugin. With out plugin also it works fine. Let me know if the problem is solved or not with further information.